# How to achieve this 'behind text' effect in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

How can I achieve this 'behind text' color effect with CSS?

[image: The text Accessibility for everyone with slanted red block behind the words for everyone]

[image: The text The Benefits with an orange block overlapping some of the letters]

[image: The text Reach your own goals with a block of colour behind the word goals]

Comment: learn about ::after \ ::before

Comment: You may visit [this](https://freefrontend.com/css-text-effects/) to get some awesome effects using `CSS`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this is not at all how you ask a proper question here. What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You are expected to invest your best effort to solve the problem by yourself first. Then, if you fail, search the web for why it might fail. If you've done all that and still didn't succeed, come back here, show your best attempt, explain how it fails and what you expect instead.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), make yourself acquainted with [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

These are the rough implementation of all the examples, and you can adjust it according to your need.

```css
h1 span {
  color: #FD1215;
  background: #FFE0E0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h2 {
  color: #10284A;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h2 span {
  background: #FC6E6B;
  padding: 5px 18px 5px 8px;
  clip-path: polygon(3% 0, 100% 0%, 90% 100%, 0% 100%);
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

h3 {
  color: #353535;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 25px;
  z-index: 1;
}

h3 span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #FCC183;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reach your own <span>goals</span></h1>

<h2>Accessbility <span>for everyone</span></h2>

<h3>The Benefits <span></span></h3>
```

Comment: Please don't encourage low quality questions that don't meet SO's standards by answering.

Comment: @connexo, I'll keep this thing in mind, thanks